# Escaping Backslash in a RegExp String

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add a backslash to the following list of allowed characters.  It must be used & passed-in as it is shown in the RegExp string below:

I have tried escaping it, but to no avail:

```
expandedText: function (e) {

        var regex = new RegExp("^[\\w., #&/-]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first escape character may be getting caught by PHP before getting to the RegEx engine. Try four backslashes?

Comment: That is, your intent is to capture word characters with `\w`, but it is not capturing word characters? Or are you trying to capture backslash and also capture a literal `w`? Or a backslash and all word characters?

Comment: @apsillers - yes, it is capturing word characters fine.  I need Backslashes too, please.

Comment: @Prisoner ZERO  I think your looking for something like this:
RegExp("^[\\\w., #&/-]+$")

Comment: @hajile78 No, that's not correct. That creates exactly the same RexEx as the one that OP already has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're creating the RegEx from a string literal, the double backslash is being interpreted as an escaped backslash *within the string* and you're winding up with this RegEx:

```
^[\w., #&/-]+$
```

This matches word characters, but backslashes are nowhere to be found.

The solution: escape both backslashes, and add one for the `\w`, resulting in six backslashes:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[\\\\\\w., #&/-]+$");
```

Or even better, use a regular expression literal and only use three backslashes:

```
var regex = /^[\\\w., #&/-]+$/;
```

Comment: Ah, yes.  The old "Sextuple Slash" technique...I should have known (*jk*)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to escaping the backslash for the regex expression, you must also escape each backslash within the string literal. That is, the string literal

```
"\\"
```

evaluates to a one-character string sequence consisting of a single backslash. Since you need two backslashes to express a single backslash in your regular expression, you need four backslashes in your string literal to express two backslashes in your regular expression:

```
"\\\\"
```

This expresses a two-character sequence in the regular expression: one backslash, preceded by an escaping backslash, to fill out out regular expression. That is, these two expressions (using a regex literal and the `RegExp` constructor)  are equivalent:

```
/\\/
new RegExp("\\\\")
```

Each of these regular expression objects will match a single backslash.

Using a the `RegExp` constructor, you can do: `new RegExp("^[\\\\\\w., #&/-]+$")`; however, it seems like a regex literal would be cleaner and shorter with no disadvantages (as you don't dynamically build your regex using a varying string):

```
var regex = /^[\\\w., #&/-]+$/
```